# Make python request to update itens at the checkout

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using this code to update some itens in my list of products

```
# Inform the payload data

payload = {
    "EPrincipal":"888407233616",
    "SiteId":106
}

# POST request

adicionar_url = "MY URL"

post = session_req.post(
adicionar_url,
data = payload
)
```

Once I try to debbug, the status code that it is returning is 200, but when I write the result using soup, I got

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

#Return
{"success": false, "site_id":"" }
```

and the itens are not updated in my account. Can someone try to help me on it?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution using the request exported by the postman using the python requests library.

```
import requests

url = "MY SITE"

payload = "Principal=9999&Site=999&g-recaptcha-response="
headers = {
  'authority': 'ROOT-SITE',
  'x-sec-clge-req-type': 'ajax',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'origin': 'https://ROOT-SITE',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'referer': 'https://ROOT-SITE',
  'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,es;q=0.5',
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: I came across this answer after searching for `x-sec-clge-req-type`, which I've found in an API I am analyzing. Do you have any idea what this field is used for? Clearly it represents the security challenge request type. Is this a common header used for recaptcha? Were you trying to automate a request using a recaptcha?